# The driver for the AverMedia DVD EZMaker 7 C039 video capture card is not installed

Tags: drivers

There is a video capture card **AverMedia DVD EZMaker 7 C039**. Ubuntu operating system 18.04. I downloaded the [driver](https://www.avermedia.com/ru/tv_more/download/dvd_ezmaker_7). When you first run the script with the command:

```
sudo ./C039_LinuxDrv_x86_V1.0.28-beta_Install_OEM.sh
```

I see `log /home/USER/driver_install_log.txt`. Installing `vlc, mplayer`. But the problem with the installation did not dare. Some errors that I found and do not understand how to fix:

```
VLC version: 
/home/USER/.config/vlc/vlcrc not exist!
```

And:

```
Running installer...
Start to compile objects...
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build  O=/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: вход в каталог «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic»
make[2]: вход в каталог «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic»
  CC [M]  /tmp/avm-install/installer/cx231xx-video.o
/tmp/avm-install/installer/cx231xx-video.c:39:10: fatal error: media/v4l2-chip-ident.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 #include <media/v4l2-chip-ident.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/tmp/avm-install/installer/cx231xx-video.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/tmp/avm-install/installer/cx231xx-video.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/avm-install/installer' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/tmp/avm-install/installer] Error 2
make[2]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic»
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic»
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
Failed to compile objects
```

Tell me what the problem is?

> UPD

`lsmod | grep cx2`:

```
cx231xx_alsa           20480  0
cx25840                65536  0
cx231xx               180224  1 cx231xx_alsa
videobuf_vmalloc       16384  1 cx231xx
tveeprom               24576  1 cx231xx
cx2341x                28672  1 cx231xx
videobuf_core          28672  2 cx231xx,videobuf_vmalloc
rc_core                36864  1 cx231xx
v4l2_common            16384  3 cx2341x,cx231xx,cx25840
i2c_mux                16384  1 cx231xx
videodev              184320  4 cx2341x,v4l2_common,cx231xx,cx25840
media                  40960  3 videodev,cx231xx,cx25840
snd_pcm                98304  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,cx231xx_alsa,snd_hda_core
snd                    81920  32 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,cx231xx_alsa,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

`dmesg | grep cx2`:

```
[23225.040235] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: New device AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc. AVerMedia C039 USB Pure Capture @ 480 Mbps (07ca:c039) with 7 interfaces
[23225.040401] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: can't change interface 4 alt no. to 3: Max. Pkt size = 0
[23225.040405] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Identified as Conexant VIDEO GRABBER (card=5)
[23225.209400] cx25840 9-0044: cx23102 A/V decoder found @ 0x88 (cx231xx #0-0)
[23227.302184] cx25840 9-0044: loaded v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw firmware (16382 bytes)
[23227.337799] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: v4l2 driver version 0.0.3
[23227.442435] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered video device video0 [v4l2]
[23227.442600] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered VBI device vbi0
[23227.442607] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: video EndPoint Addr 0x84, Alternate settings: 5
[23227.442613] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: VBI EndPoint Addr 0x85, Alternate settings: 2
[23227.442619] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: sliced CC EndPoint Addr 0x86, Alternate settings: 2
[23227.442624] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: TS EndPoint Addr 0x81, Alternate settings: 6
[23227.859220] usbcore: registered new interface driver cx231xx
[23227.869593] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: audio EndPoint Addr 0x83, Alternate settings: 3
[23227.869596] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Cx231xx Audio Extension initialized
[23244.400957] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device vbi0 deregistered
[23244.401066] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device video0 deregistered
[23260.243409] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: New device AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc. AVerMedia C039 USB Pure Capture @ 480 Mbps (07ca:c039) with 7 interfaces
[23260.243538] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: can't change interface 4 alt no. to 3: Max. Pkt size = 0
[23260.243549] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Identified as Conexant VIDEO GRABBER (card=5)
[23260.558341] cx25840 9-0044: cx23102 A/V decoder found @ 0x88 (cx231xx #0-0)
[23262.675378] cx25840 9-0044: loaded v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw firmware (16382 bytes)
[23262.710130] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: v4l2 driver version 0.0.3
[23262.813249] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered video device video0 [v4l2]
[23262.813351] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered VBI device vbi0
[23262.813849] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: audio EndPoint Addr 0x83, Alternate settings: 3
[23262.813854] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: video EndPoint Addr 0x84, Alternate settings: 5
[23262.813860] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: VBI EndPoint Addr 0x85, Alternate settings: 2
[23262.813864] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: sliced CC EndPoint Addr 0x86, Alternate settings: 2
[23262.813869] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: TS EndPoint Addr 0x81, Alternate settings: 6
[24566.767572] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device vbi0 deregistered
[24566.767756] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device video0 deregistered
[26138.908641] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: New device AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc. AVerMedia C039 USB Pure Capture @ 480 Mbps (07ca:c039) with 7 interfaces
[26138.908834] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: can't change interface 4 alt no. to 3: Max. Pkt size = 0
[26138.908846] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Identified as Conexant VIDEO GRABBER (card=5)
[26139.037788] cx25840 9-0044: cx23102 A/V decoder found @ 0x88 (cx231xx #0-0)
[26141.145821] cx25840 9-0044: loaded v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw firmware (16382 bytes)
[26141.180309] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: v4l2 driver version 0.0.3
[26141.280556] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered video device video0 [v4l2]
[26141.280604] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: Registered VBI device vbi0
[26141.281025] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: audio EndPoint Addr 0x83, Alternate settings: 3
[26141.281028] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: video EndPoint Addr 0x84, Alternate settings: 5
[26141.281036] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: VBI EndPoint Addr 0x85, Alternate settings: 2
[26141.281038] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: sliced CC EndPoint Addr 0x86, Alternate settings: 2
[26141.281041] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: TS EndPoint Addr 0x81, Alternate settings: 6
[27100.060278] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device vbi0 deregistered
[27100.060366] cx231xx 1-1:1.1: V4L2 device video0 deregistered
```

Comment: No circa-2011 driver package that was built for kernel version 2.6.xx is ever going to compile in any recent Ubuntu version. Is this a USB device? What does `lsusb` report about it?

Comment: @chili555 Yes, it is. `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07ca:c039 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc.`.

Comment: It appears that the already built-in driver cx231xx covers your device: `alias:          usb:v07CApC039` Did the driver load" `lsmod | grep cx2` Are there informative messages in the log? `dmesg | grep cx2` Please edit your question to add the results. Firmware, methinks!

Comment: @chili555 Corrected

Comment: I'm really not at all familiar with this device, but you appear to be all set. Firmware was found and loaded. No errors or warnings. I don't know what else to do except start capturing video.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked, there were some [significant changes to the kernel's cx231xx driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7c617138b8254a6bb60bfb5b8fc53eb8b3d6c3ab). I can confirm that with a recent kernel (5.10) the driver works as expected.

Here's the dmesg log when I connected the device:

```
[Sat Dec 17 21:47:22 2022] usbcore: registered new interface driver cx231xx
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=07ca, idProduct=c039, bcdDevice=40.01
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: Product: AVerMedia C039 USB Pure Capture
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc.
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 311510200470
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: New device AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc. AVerMedia C039 USB Pure Capture @ 480 Mbps (07ca:c039) with 7 interfaces
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: can't change interface 4 alt no. to 3: Max. Pkt size = 0
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: Identified as Conexant VIDEO GRABBER (card=5)
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] i2c i2c-21: Added multiplexed i2c bus 23
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] i2c i2c-21: Added multiplexed i2c bus 24
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] cx25840 20-0044: cx23102 A/V decoder found @ 0x88 (cx231xx #0-0)
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:14 2022] cx25840 20-0044: firmware: direct-loading firmware v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx25840 20-0044: loaded v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw firmware (16382 bytes)
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: v4l2 driver version 0.0.3
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: Registered video device video2 [v4l2]
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: Registered VBI device vbi0
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: video EndPoint Addr 0x84, Alternate settings: 5
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: VBI EndPoint Addr 0x85, Alternate settings: 2
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: sliced CC EndPoint Addr 0x86, Alternate settings: 2
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:16 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: TS EndPoint Addr 0x81, Alternate settings: 6
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:17 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: audio EndPoint Addr 0x83, Alternate settings: 3
[Sat Dec 17 21:49:17 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: Cx231xx Audio Extension initialized
```

I tested in OBS Studio by adding a "Video Capture Device" with these settings:

[image: Settings]

Then when I disconnected the device:

```
[Sun Dec 18 00:15:34 2022] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 58
[Sun Dec 18 00:15:34 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: V4L2 device vbi0 deregistered
[Sun Dec 18 00:15:34 2022] cx231xx 2-2:1.1: V4L2 device video2 deregistered
```

These last 2 lines happen to be recurrent in the logs shared in the question. It's possible that there was a flaky connection, which could be related or not to the older driver.